# Can CSS convert a string to integer?

Tags: css, pseudo-class, custom-data-attribute

I use `attr(data-width)` to get the `data-width`-attribute from some `list-item`'s. I try to use these values to set the width of that element.

The problem is that css cannot handle strings as `width`/`height`-value.
e.g.:

```
<foo data-width='100%'></foo>

/* can not work */
foo {
    width: attr(data-width)
}
```

so I need to convert the value from the `data`-attribute to an integer (+unit).

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. Wrongly duped question happened on SO so frequently. For example, by converting <string> to <integer>. Not only attr() may yield string values, but also counter() function. And attr() now accept a new parameter to convert its type. So this question is far from a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. And you cannot use an `attr(...)` construct as the value of a normal property, only in the value of a `content` property.

Instead of `data-width` attributes, you could use just `style` attributes. Not ideal, but more logical than to use `data-*` attributes to carry style info.

Comment: ~5 Years to accept your answer... Shame on me!

Answer (score -1):

not without a precompiler and SASS / SCSS mixins

Comment: I don't think that this works: http://fiddle.jshell.net/pA3Kq/

Comment: Preprocessors generate the CSS *first* and only the compiled CSS is sent to the browser.  They have no way of taking the information from the DOM and turning it into an integer and CSS does not have that ability natively.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't make any sense because there's no content to make the element visible:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/pA3Kq/1/.  As you can see, the element does not extend all the way to the edge of the document.

Comment: @cimmanon just replace `attr(data-width)` with `100%` in my fiddle ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 this was just a simple test using SCSS as preprocessor

Comment: @yckart Aaaaaaah. Now it's becoming clear :-)